# ion-reorder items will not drag/reorder in Ionic 4 application

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to use ion-reorder in my Ionic 4/Angular application. I have copy/pasted from the online document, but I just cannot drag the items.

For example, as from [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v4/api/reorder), I have the following:

```
        <ion-content style="width: 100%; height: 100%" (ionScrollStart)='ionScrollStart()' (ionScrollEnd)='ionScrollEnd()'>
        <ion-list style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            
            <ion-reorder-group (ionItemReorder)="doReorder($event)" disabled="false">
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>
                        Item 1
                    </ion-label>
                    <ion-reorder slot="start"></ion-reorder>
                </ion-item>
        
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>
                        Item 2
                    </ion-label>
                    <ion-reorder slot="start"></ion-reorder>
                </ion-item>
        
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>
                        Item 3
                    </ion-label>
                    <ion-reorder slot="start"></ion-reorder>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-reorder-group>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
```

I see the reorder lines, and the had appears when I click on it, but the items just will not drag. Also, when I click the mouse, the hand cursor does not close like in the example.

[image]

I have nothing fancy here, so just not sure why it won't work.

My ionic info is

```
    $ ionic info

    Ionic:

         Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 (C:\Users\pchapman\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
         Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.13
         @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.29
         @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.29
         @angular/cli                  : 8.2.2
         @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

    Cordova:

         Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0 (cordova-lib@10.1.0)
         Cordova Platforms : android 10.1.1, ios 6.2.0, windows 7.0.1
         Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 15 other plugins)

    Utility:

         cordova-res : 0.15.3
         native-run  : 0.2.9

    System:

         Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\pchapman\AppData\Local\Android\sdk)
         NodeJS            : v14.17.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
         npm               : 7.21.1
         OS                : Windows 10
```

I have tried this in a page (they are all lazy loaded - hope nothing to do with that), and in a popup component, it it just won't work at all (and yet it does in the doco, and another examples)

Why might this be?

### Update 1

Trying to debug into this, this is the line where it is failing....

[image]

`target` appears to the hamburger image...

[image]

So it appears the `target.closest('ion-reorder')` is ont finding the `ion-reorder`.

And this in turn makes the mousedown do nothing...

[image]

I see that there is a shadow root boundary between these two elements. Can `closest()` transverse this boundary?

[image]

And if not, how could this component be working for anyone, which is obviously is, so why not for me?

All just guessing here...

Comment: Hello! Could you please create a stackblitz demo where we can reproduce the issue? That way it'd be easier to find what's happening behind the scenes. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonReorderGroup } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'reorder-group-example',
  templateUrl: 'reorder-group-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reorder-group-example.css']
})
export class ReorderGroupExample {
  @ViewChild(IonReorderGroup) reorderGroup: IonReorderGroup;

  constructor() {}

  doReorder(ev: any) {
    // The `from` and `to` properties contain the index of the item
    // when the drag started and ended, respectively
    console.log('Dragged from index', ev.detail.from, 'to', ev.detail.to);

    // Finish the reorder and position the item in the DOM based on
    // where the gesture ended. This method can also be called directly
    // by the reorder group
    ev.detail.complete();
  }

  toggleReorderGroup() {
    this.reorderGroup.disabled = !this.reorderGroup.disabled;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, yes I did have all of that. My doReorder is never called